# How to use an inline if with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create an inline if with razor has follows:

```
@(Model.ImageId == null ?  "---" : @<text><img src='@(Url.Action(MVC.File.Get(Model.ImageId)))'/></text>)
```

I keep getting the errors:

```
 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'lambda expression'

 cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'string'
```

How can I solve this using an inline if

Answer (score 0):

Razor does not have a nice syntax to output what you described. It is possible to use what is defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223692/3697011).

If it was my code I wanted to use ternary operator I would probably create a Razor helper method and use it in such way:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.ImageId == null ? "---" : OutputImageName(Model.ImageId).ToHtmlString())

@helper OutputImageName(string imageId /* change type to your actual type */)
{
    <img src='@(Url.Action(MVC.File.Get(imageId)))'/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@(Model.ImageId == null ?  "---" : string.Format(@"<text><img src='{0}'/></text>", Url.Action(MVC.File.Get(Model.ImageId))))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<text>@(Model.ImageId == null ?  "" : string.Format("<img src='{0}'/>", Url.Action(MVC.File.Get(Model.ImageId))))</text>
```

Comment: While this may solve the question, this post would be much more valuable if you provided additional explanations.